# Getting data from ArrayList in a diffrent class

Tags: android, class, android-intent, arraylist

I'm doing pars from a json api to my array list as ;

```
  package com.example.dovizkuru;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

public class DownloadDovizTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{

    public interface GetDovizResponseCallback{
        void dovizLoadingFinished(String response);
    }

    GetDovizResponseCallback getDovizResponseCallback;

    public DownloadDovizTask(GetDovizResponseCallback getDovizResponseCallback) {
        this.getDovizResponseCallback = getDovizResponseCallback;
    }
     @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
         Log.d("URL", urls[0]);
         String url = urls[0];
          String response = "";

            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
            try {
              HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpGet);
              InputStream content = execute.getEntity().getContent();

              BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
              String s = "";
              while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                response += s;
              }

            } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }

          Log.d("URL", "RESPONSE: "+response);
          return response;
           }
   @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
       getDovizResponseCallback.dovizLoadingFinished(result);

        }
    }
```

then i get it in an ArrayList like

```
@Override
public void dovizLoadingFinished(String response) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ArrayList<String> list1=new ArrayList<String>();
    JSONArray jsonArrayDoviz;
    try {
        JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
        jsonArrayDoviz = jObj.getJSONArray("value");
            dovizList.clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArrayDoviz.length(); i++) {

                Doviz doviz = new Doviz();

                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArrayDoviz.getJSONObject(i);
                doviz.setAdi(jsonObject.getString("adi"));  
                doviz.setAlis(jsonObject.getString("alis"));
                doviz.setSatis(jsonObject.getString("satis"));
                doviz.setKey(jsonObject.getString("key"));
                doviz.setOran(jsonObject.getString("oran"));
                doviz.setType(jsonObject.getString("type"));
                doviz.setUpDown(jsonObject.getString("upDown"));
                list1.add(doviz.getAdi());
                list1.add(doviz.getAlis());
                list1.add(doviz.getSatis());
                dovizList.add(doviz);

            }       
    } catch (JSONException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } 

    ListView listview =(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    adapter = new Adapter(this,dovizList);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

then at another class i am trying to get data which is the alis value from the ArrayList but it returns null/zero back to me.

I tried making a GetArraylist(); function to get the arraylist first
I also tried to make the ArrayList declarations as public static

By the way the new class i'm trying to access data from is in another intent. And my parsing works fine i list them in my first intent which .

so any other way for me to get data from this ArrayList ?

Thanks for helps in advance .

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution its using public static at lists then getting them in the new class. The reason it didn't work before was due to some bad feedback from API i used try a catch with replacing possible bad  feedback which is giving me ',' instead of '.' in some places and it works.